# Omit namespace from XML file before loading to Marklogic database

Tags: marklogic

I am loading some xml files in Marklogic database using Templates and mlcp import.
One namespace in those files is not allowing the data import in the marklogic though there is no error thrown after executing the mlcp import command.

When I omit that particular namespace from the files, the data gets imported successfully.

Can we use any command to omit the namespace prior hand before loading the data in marklogic ?
The namespace which creating issue is - xmlns="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment

Sample XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Shipment xmlns:ns10="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/ASN" 
xmlns:ns9="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/BaseType"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment file:///Y:/MapForce/Projects/GTM2/schema/Shipment.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment">
    <ns9:DocumentHeader>
        <ns9:DocRef>123</ns9:DocRef>
        <ns9:DocCreateDt>2021-10-21T13:01:39.2521396+01:00</ns9:DocCreateDt>
        <ns9:DocType>Shipment</ns9:DocType>
    </ns9:DocumentHeader>
    <ns10:ASN>
        <ns9:DocumentHeader>
            <ns9:DocRef>123</ns9:DocRef>
            <ns9:DocType>ASN</ns9:DocType>
            <ns9:DocModified>0000000</ns9:DocModified>
            <ns9:DocModifiedDt xsi:nil="true" />
            </ns9:DocumentHeader>
        <ns10:OSP xmlns:ns10="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/ASN">
            <ns9:PartyName />
        </ns10:OSP>
        <ns10:MultiFreightJobHeader>
            <MultiFreightRef xmlns="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/ASN">SEIIUSJ00010129</MultiFreightRef>
            <Dept xmlns="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/ASN">SEI</Dept>
            <Route xmlns="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/ASN">IUS</Route>
        </ns10:MultiFreightJobHeader>
    </ns10:ASN>
</Shipment>
```

Comment: Example input XML would be helpful, to understand if the issue is an unused namespace declaration, or a namespace prefix that doesn't have a namespace declaration (invalid XML)

Comment: Added a sample XML in the question description.

Comment: xmlns="http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment

The namespace which needs to be omitted to load the file successfully

Comment: that namespace declaration has no prefix, so any elements that don't have a namespace-prefix will have that namespace.

Comment: so, if you are having trouble processing the data in your TDE templates, you could just update the XPaths to address content in that namespace instead of dropping it from your input XML

Comment: I have already defined the namespaces in the template itself. Like this -

 **<path-namespace>
    <prefix>xmlns</prefix>
    <namespace-uri>http://www.globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment</namespace-uri>
  </path-namespace>**

Not sure , if you have suggested this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244683/discussion-between-rashmita-purkayastha-and-mads-hansen).

Comment: Solution as you suggested - 
I have added the namespaces in the template itself. Like this - <path-namespace> <prefix>xmlns:ns99</prefix> <namespace-uri>globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment</na‌​mespace-uri> </path-namespace> 
I have then added the prefix(ns99) with this namespace and appended that namespace-prefix for all the elements which doesnot have any namespace-prefix , and I did this in my template definition. 
And it worked successfully !! Thanks @Madshansen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution as suggested by @Madshansen - I have added the namespaces in the template itself. Like this -

```
<path-namespace> 
  <prefix>xmlns:ns99</prefix> 
  <namespace-uri>globaltrademanagement_export.com/Shipment</na‌​mespace-uri> 
</path-namespace>
```

I have then added the prefix(ns99) with this namespace and appended that namespace-prefix for all the elements which does not have any namespace-prefix, and I did this in my template definition. And it worked successfully !! Thanks @Madshansen

Comment: Just a note that you don't have to modify your source XML to use a prefix. Those elements would be bound to that namespace regardless. The prefix from the source XML doesn't have to match what you use for your XPath, but the NAMESPACE assigned to the prefix used in your XPath does have to match the namespace of the element.